# Bash Script search and replace

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a bash script that isn't properly working, I am new to this type of coding.  Any suggestions or help would be great.

I am attempting to change email addresses of an old user with a new user across our PuTTy platform.  However not all directories have a certain file, I think there may be a problem with my IF statement.  Here is the script I have attempted using:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

for dirs in *
do
  echo $dirs
  cd $dirs/
  if [ -d "Seadont"]
  then 
   sed -i 's/USER1/USER2/g'
  ls
  fi
done
```

My results are not correct.

Comment: One problem is that you need a space before `]`

Comment: Second problem is that you need to pass an argument to `sed`

Comment: And don't need to run `cd` command since it will fail after first iteration.

Comment: And you don't specify a file name for `sed` to work on, so it will fail because the `-i` option cannot rename standard input.  If you must use `cd`, use a sub-shell: `( cd "$dirs/"; ... )` so that when the sub-shell is complete, the original shell hasn't changed directory (so you can `cd` to another directory).  You might do better with `for dirs in */Seadont`, too.

Comment: Thank you, I will make these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

for dirs in * ;do
  echo $dirs
  if [ -d "Seadont"] ;then 
     sed -i.bak 's/USER1/USER2/g' $dirs 
   fi
done
```

Mind you that it won't work if there are white spaces on "$dirs". I can propose a better solution if it does, but I would need to know current directory.